# Meteor: how to detect a new user to display an app intro screen?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cookies, meteor

How to know that the user is a first time user?

Needs to work with anonymous users (before they've logged in) and must remember if the user has already dismissed the intro screen even after updates of the app.

This is for a web and mobile app (Android and iOS)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When the use dismisses the intro screen, store a persistent session variable. Check this package https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session for more information.

Before displaying the intro message, check is the session variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a SessionManager class for yourself and store such data inside a specific session. Anyway, you can use these two methods to write and read the firstEnter.

```
public static void setFirstEnter(Context context)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("YourAppNameExp", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("FirstEnter", true);
    editor.commit();
}

public static boolean isFirstEnter(Context context)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("YourAppNameExp", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPref.getBoolean("FirstEnter", false);
}
```

And then use them in onPause method of the activity:

```
public void onPause()
{
    if(SessionManager.isFirstEnter(this))
    {
         SessionManager.setFirstEnter(this);
         // Do what you want...
    }
}
```